# Tasypie, how to prevent modification on a resource linked by a ForeignKey

Tags: django, tastypie

I have 2 resources that are linked by a foreignKey

I would like to make the AUser resource read-only when creating/modifying AJob

```
class AUser(ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        queryset = User.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'user'
        authentication = SessionAuthentication()
        authorization = Authorization()
        excludes = ['email', 'password', 'is_superuser', 'is_staff', 'is_active', 'date_joined', 'last_login']
    def can_update(self):
        return False  
    def can_create(self):
        return False
    def can_delete(self):
        return False
    def apply_authorization_limits(self, request, object_list):
        return object_list.filter(pk=request.user.pk)

class AJob(ModelResource):
    user = fields.ForeignKey( AUser, 'user', full=True)
    paused = fields.BooleanField(attribute='isPaused', readonly=True)
    hasRules = fields.BooleanField(attribute='hasRules', readonly=True)
    class Meta:
        queryset = Job.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'job'
        authentication = SessionAuthentication()
        api_name = 'v1'
        authorization = Authorization()
        allowed_methods = ['get', 'post', 'delete']

    def obj_create(self, bundle, request=None, **kwargs):
        return super(AJob, self).obj_create(bundle, request, user=request.user)

    def apply_authorization_limits(self, request, object_list):
        return object_list.filter(user=request.user)
```

I tried adding readonly=True to the foreignKey directly but then it's ignored when hydrating
and get a constraint violation because user is null

if in my POST AJob request I append

> "user":{"id":"5","is_staff":false}

5 being the current user

the User model get updated, removing the admin role

it seems that tastypie when doing save_related does not check any authorization

How can I make this User resource read-only ?

I am using tastypie v0.9.12-alpha

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can modify the `save_related` method inside the `AJob` resource and define it not to modify the `AUser`. You can define the ForeignKey do be readonly as you wanted to but then you have to supply the `dehydrate_user` method and inside get the value that you want to return. It will be something like `return bundle['data'].user`.

Comment: I d have to try the readonly and dehydrate_user, returning the user in the session, that sounds like a reasonable approach. thanks :)